# ModuleNotFoundError while module is installed by rosdep and can be found in environment

Tags: ros2, rosdep, rosdistro

I am trying to make my first 'hello world' application for a GUI application interacting with my robot using PyQt6 and Ros2 (humble). In `package.xml` I have declared the PyQt6 dependency: `<exec_depend>python3-pyqt6</exec_depend>`. It does not yet exist in python.yaml so I [forked the rosdistro, changed the sources.list.d direction to my local python.yaml](http://docs.ros.org/en/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html) and added:

```
python3-pyqt6:
  ubuntu:
    pip:
      packages: [PyQt6]
```

This all works in that rosdep sees the dependency and installs PyQt6 which can be found when doing a `pip freeze`. Running python, `import PyQt6` all without a problem.

When I run the application (after `colcon build`, `source install/setup.bash`) like `ros2 run frontend front` yields the error:

```
File "/media/i-files/home/arnold/development/ros2/interfaces/install/frontend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/frontend/front.py", line 5, in <module>
    import PyQt6
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt6'
```

I have no idea where this is coming from because all my indicators tell me PyQt6 is installed. Replacing the 6 by a 5 (PyQt5) runs the application without a hitch.  Anybody sees what I am doing wrong?

The code for front.py is:

```
mport sys
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

import PyQt6
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

from robot_interfaces.msg import Distance

class MinimalSubscriber(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('frontend_subscriber')
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            Distance,
            'topic',
            self.listener_callback,
            10)
        self.subscription  # prevent unused variable warning

        return

    def listener_callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info(f'Received {msg.distance} ({msg.status})')

        return
    

def main():
    print('Hi from frontend.')

    # You need one (and only one) QApplication instance per application.
    # Pass in sys.argv to allow command line arguments for your app.
    # If you know you won't use command line arguments QApplication([]) works too.
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create a Qt widget, which will be our window.
    window = QWidget()
    window.show()  # IMPORTANT!!!!! Windows are hidden by default.

    # Start the event loop.
    app.exec()

    # Your application won't reach here until you exit and the event
    # loop has stopped.

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```